# Weighted algorithm to find similar players

Tags: algorithm, math

I would like to work out the closest match for each of the players at my local badminton club based on their scores. All the games are singles. The winner is the first one to 21 points and with 2 clear points. If the first to 21 doesn't have 2 clear points then play will continue and the winner will be the first with 2 clear points or the first to 30 points (whichever comes first). Thus the winner can have a score ranging from 21 to 30 and the loser can have a score ranging from 0 to 29.

I can work out the similarity between two players by working out their average score difference. The lower the average, the more similar the players.

However, I would like to give a greater weighting for those that have played more games vs those that have played few.

What and how is the best way to add a fair weighting that will scale from any number of games played?

TIA

Comment: Are you asking about the average of head-to-head score differences for each pair of players?  Then there might be a lot of information about a pair who play frequently, and little or no information about similarity of players who pair off rarely.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I'm after. Player A vs Player B who have only played each other once may have a lower average point difference than Player A vs Player C even though A vs C have played many more games. If the average differences are quite small then I would like for Player C to be more similar to Player A. But I don't know how to work in the number of games played into the calculation in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the notion of [confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) from statistics.  The size of a confidence interval depends (statistically) both on the sample size (which corresponds to number of games played) and on the variance of the underlying population.  The length of the confidence interval decreases with sample size (as you have more data for estimation) and increases with increasing variance of the underlying population.

Of course you are not doing a rigorous statistical analysis, so you have the freedom to apply the ideas of confidence intervals in a formula that suits your purpose.  As you'll see in the linked article, when estimating the mean of a normal population, the size of the confidence interval decreases with the square root of the sample size.  So you could artificially use that factor in your formula with "heuristic" justification.

Comment: **Added:** When I mention "a formula that suits your purpose", I had in mind that you perhaps are looking for a "distance-like" quantity that measure how close two players are, or perhaps again a signed quantity that might indicate which of two players is stronger.  Either could be considered a measure of similarity, but of course you'd wnat different formulas depending on the application.  Let me know more and I'll give an example.